# Unit Of Work and Repository inter dependency

Tags: repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I have seen lots of posts (and debates!) about which way round UnitOfWork and Repository. One of the repository patterns I favor is the typed generic repository pattern, but I fear this had lead to some issues with clean code and testability. Take the following repository interface and generic class:

```
public interface IDataEntityRepository<T> : IDisposable where T : IDataEntity
{
   // CRUD
   int Create(T createObject);
   // etc.
}


public class DataEntityRepository<T> : IDataEntityRepository<T> where T : class, IDataEntity
{
   private IDbContext Context { get; set; }

   public DataEntityRepository (IDbContext context)
   {
     Context = context;
   }

   private IDbSet<T> DbSet { get { return Context.Set<T>(); } }   

   public int Create(T CreateObject)
   {
      DbSet.Add(createObject);
   }

   // etc.

}

// where

public interface IDbContext
{
   IDbSet<T> Set<T>() where T : class;
   DbEntityEntry<T> Entry<T>(T readObject) where T : class;

   int SaveChanges();
   void Dispose();
}
```

So basically I am using the Context property in each pattern to gain access to the underlying context.
My problem is now this: when I create my unit of work, it will effectively be a wrapper of the context I need the repository to know about. So, if I have a Unit Of Work that declares the following:

```
public UserUnitOfWork(
    IDataEntityRepository<User> userRepository,
    IDataEntityRepository<Role> roleRepository)
{
    _userRepository = userRepository;
    _roleRepository = roleRepository;
}

private readonly IDataEntityRepository<User> _userRepository;

public IDataEntityRepository<User> UserRepository
{
    get { return _userRepository; }
}

private readonly IDataEntityRepository<Role> _roleRepository;

public IDataEntityRepository<Role> RoleRepository
{
    get { return _roleRepository; }
}
```

I have a problem with the fact that the two repositories I am passing in both need to be instantiated with the very Unit Of Work into which they are being passed. Obviously I could instantiate the repositories inside the constructor and pass in the "this" but that tightly couples my unit of work to a particular concrete instance of the repositories and makes unit testing that much harder.
I would be interested to know if anyone else has headed down this path and hit the same wall. Both these patterns are new to me so I could well be doing something fundamentally wrong. Any ideas would be much appreciated!

### UPDATE (response to @MikeSW)

Hi Mike, many thanks for your input. I am working with EF Code First but I wanted to abstract certain elements so I could switch to a different data source or ORM if required and because I am (trying!) to push myself down a TDD route and using Mocking and IOC. I think I have realised the hard way that certain elements cannot be unit tested in a pure sense but can have integration tests! I'd like to raise your point about Repositories working with business objects or viewmodels etc. Perhaps I have misunderstood but if I have what I see as my core business objects (POCOs), and I then want to use an ORM such as EF code first to wrap around those entities in order to create, and then interact with, the database (and, it's possible, I may re-use these entities within a ViewModel), I would expect a Repository to handle these entities directly in the context of some set of CRUD operations. The entities know nothing about the persistence layer at all, neither would any ViewModel. My unit of work simply instantiates and holds the required repositories allowing a transaction commit to be performed (across multiple repositories but the same context/ session). What I have done in my solution is to remove the injection of an IDataEntityRepository ... etc. from the UnitOfWork constructor as this is a concrete class that must know about one and only one type of IDataEntityRepository it should be creating (in this case DataEntityRepository, which really should be bettered names as EFDataEntityRepository). I cannot unit test this per se because the whole unit logic would be to establish the repositories with a context (itself) to some database. It simply needs an integration test. Hope that makes sense?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apologies for the tardiness of my response - I have been trying out various approaches to this in the mean time. I have marked up the answers above because I agree with the comments made.

This is one of those questions where there is more than one answer and it's very much dependent upon the overall approach. Whilst I agree that EF effectively provides a ready-made unit of work pattern, my decision to create my own unit of work and repository layers was to be able to control access to the database entities.

Where I struggled was in the need to be able to inject a repository into a unit of work. What I realised though was that in the case of EF, my unit of work was effectively a thin wrapper around multiple repositories with a Commit (SaveChanges) method. It was not responsible for executing specific actions such as FindCustomer etc.

So I decided that a unit of work could be tightly coupled to its specific type of DataRepository pattern. To ensure I had a testable pattern, I introduced a service layer that provided the facade for executing particular actions such as CreateCustomer, FindCustomers etc. These services that accepted an IUnitOfWork constructor parameter which provided access to the repositories (as interfaces) as well as the Commit method.

I was then able to create fakes of both unit of work and/ or repositories for testing purposes. This just left me with the decision of what could be unit tested with fakes and what needed to be integration tested with the concrete instances.

And this also gives me the opportunity to control what actions are performed on the database and how they are performed.

I'm sure there are many ways to skin this particular cat but the goals of provided a clean interface that is testable have been just about met with this approach.

My thanks to g1ga and Mike for their input.

Comment: Just read this post and it is interesting that I had come to the same conclusion about the coupling of unit of work and repository.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid dependency on each repository in your Unit of Work, you could use a provider based on this contract:

```
public interface IRepositoryProvider
{
    DbContext DbContext { get; set; }
    IRepository<T> GetRepositoryForEntityType<T>() where T : class;
    T GetRepository<T>(Func<DbContext, object> factory = null) where T : class;
    void SetRepository<T>(T repository);
}
```

then you could inject it into your UoW that would look like this:

```
public class UserUnitOfWork: IUserUnitOfWork
{
    public UserUnitOfWork(IRepositoryProvider repositoryProvider)
    {
        RepositoryProvider = repositoryProvider;
    }

    protected IDataEntityRepository<T> GetRepo<T>() where T : class
    {
        return RepositoryProvider.GetRepositoryForEntityType<T>();
    }

    public IDataEntityRepository<User> Users { get { return GetRepo<User>(); } }        
    public IDataEntityRepository<Role> Roles { get { return GetRepo<Role>(); } }        
...
```

Answer (score 2):

When using Entity Framework (EF) (which I assume you're using) you already have a generic repository IDbSet. It's useless to ad another layer on top just to call EF methods.

Also, a repository works with application objects (usually business objects, but they can be view models or objects state). If you're just using db entities, you kinda defeat the Repository pattern purpose ( to isolate the business bojects from the database). THe original pattern deals only with busines objects, but it is a useful pattern outside the business layer too.

The point is that EF entities are Persistence objects and have (or should have) no relation to your business objects. You want to use the repository pattern to 'translate' the busines objects to persistence objects and viceversa.

Sometimes it might happen that an application object (like a viewmodel) to be the same with a persistence entity (and in that case you can use directly EF objects) but that's a coincidence.

About Unit of Work (UoW), let's say that's tricky. Personally, I prefer to use the DDD (domain driven design) approach and consider that any business object (BO) sent to the repoistory is a UoW, so it will be wrapped in a transaction.

If I need to update multiple BOs, I'll use a message driven architecture to send commands to the relevant BOs. Of course, that's more complicated and requires to be at ease with the concept of eventual consistency but I'm not depending on a specific RDBMS.

If you know that you'll be using a specific RDBMS and that will never be changed, you could start a transaction and pass the associated connection to each repository, with a commit at the end (that will be the UoW). If you're in a web setting, it's even easier, start transaction when the request begins, commit when requests ends (you can use an ActionFilter for ASp.Net Mvc).

However this solution is tied up to one RDBMS, so it won't apply to a NoSql or any storage which doesn't support transactions. For those cases, the message driven way is the best.

Comment: I'd argue that your EF entities ARE your business models. Let the ORM do the heavy lifting of mapping your business design to your persistence design.

Comment: @Spivonious ORM is a failed experiment/solution (it works well only with simplistic models) . If a business model can be easily implemented using an ORM (without any drawbacks) then you're dealing with a CRUD app and it's ok. For everything else (business process, distributed apps etc) I' d stay away of an ORM.

Comment: the ORM concept itself is a great solution to the problem of O/R mismatch. Implementations are less than stellar. You're right that at some point the complexity of setting up the mappings takes up more time than just coding the O/R interactions from scratch, but I've found that most LoB apps are CRUD with some logic on top. EF is perfect for that use case and saves me the time of setting up DbCommands and mapping DbReader results.

EF makes it trivial to map one table to multiple classes or multiple tables to one class. Why not use it?

Comment: Many devs are misusing the ORM and personally, my DAO needs are fulfilled by a data mapper. And I prefer as little abstraction as possible these days, SQL is great at its job.

Comment: Agreed! Many devs are using ORM for simple database reads. This is total overkill and could easily be done with straight ADO.NET or a library like Dapper.